# Custom font does not load

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, fonts

So I'm creating a full stack React/Node site, my custom fonts don't load on half my pages so far though, one with loads of content and one with no content.. and then they do work on one with loads of content and one with no content ?!? and I have another front end only page where they did originally worked and then stopped working again

I'm assuming its because I'm on a ubuntu virtual machine on my laptop using 5gb ram, is there anything I can do to make it work? I think I can add more ram eventually but is there another fix?

im using chakra UI as well

font face

```
import { Global } from "@emotion/react";
const Fonts = () => (
  <Global
    styles={`
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'BebasNeue';
      src: url(fonts/BebasNeue-Regular.woff) format('woff');
    }
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Vollkorn';
      src: url(fonts/Vollkorn.woff) format('woff');
    }
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Neoneon';
      src: url(fonts/Neoneon.woff) format('woff');
    } `}
  />
);

export default Fonts;
```

My pre loads in html

```
 <link
      rel="preload"
      as="font"
      href="./fonts/BebasNeue-Regular.woff2"
      type="font/woff2"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      value="valid"
    />
    <link
      rel="preload"
      as="font"
      href="./fonts/Neoneon.woff2"
      type="font/woff2"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      value="valid"
    />
    <link
      rel="preload"
      as="font"
      href="./fonts/Vollkorn.woff2"
      type="font/woff2"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      value="valid"
    />
```

the error codes

```
ownloadable font: download failed (font-family: "Neoneon" style:normal weight:400 stretch:100 src index:0): status=2147746065 source: http://localhost:3000/recipe/fonts/Neoneon.woff

The resource at “http://localhost:3000/recipe/fonts/BebasNeue-Regular.woff2” preloaded with link preload was not used within a few seconds. Make sure all attributes of the preload tag are set correctly.

Proxy error: Could not proxy request /recipe/fonts/Vollkorn.woff from localhost:3000 to http://localhost/5000.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED)
```

Comment: not saying this is the solution, but why is `woff` in the CSS, but `woff2` in the link href?

Comment: Question: why are you doing this in JSX instead of using a normal CSS stylesheet? These are static assets, there is no reason to put the load instructions for these inside whatever bundle you're making.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I was using woff2 and changed to woff to see if it worked and it's in jsx to use with chakra ui

Answer (score 1):

This works for me using chakra and nextjs.

create a file `styles.css` with

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Font";
  src: url('../your/path/Font.woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

in your `index.js`

```
import '../path/styles.css'
```

then you can use `fontFamily` properties or use in your theme

```
export default extendTheme({
  // ...

  fonts: {
    body: `Font`,
  },
})
```

do you don't need to use `link` and `Global` component